# Unresolved import error E0432 when creating a syntax extension

Tags: rust

I'm trying to [make a syntax extension](https://www.gulshansingh.com/posts/how-to-write-a-rust-syntax-extension/), but I got error E0432. I read about it in [the error index](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0432) but could not understand what I should do!

The error text I got is:

```
/Users/hasan/.cargo/bin/cargo run --color=always --package rust01 --bin rust01

Compiling rust01 v0.1.0 (file:///Users/hasan/PycharmProjects/rust01)

error[E0432]: unresolved import `rustc::plugin`  --> src/lib.rs:6:12
| 6
| use rustc::plugin::Registry;
|            ^^^^^^ Could not find `plugin` in `rustc`

error[E0432]: unresolved import
`syntax::ext::base::SyntaxExtension::Modifier`   --> src/lib.rs:12:5
| 12
| use syntax::ext::base::SyntaxExtension::Modifier;
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `Modifier` in `ext::base::SyntaxExtension`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `syntax::parse::token::intern`   -->
src/lib.rs:13:5
| 13
| use syntax::parse::token::intern;
|     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `intern` in `parse::token`
```

This happened with my IDE:

```
#![feature(plugin_registrar, rustc_private)]

extern crate syntax; extern crate rustc;

use rustc::plugin::Registry;

use syntax::ptr::P; use syntax::ast::{Item, MetaItem}; use syntax::ext::base::ExtCtxt; use syntax::codemap::Span; use syntax::ext::base::SyntaxExtension::Modifier; use syntax::parse::token::intern;

#[plugin_registrar] pub fn registrar(reg: &mut Registry) {
    reg.register_syntax_extension(intern("extension"), Modifier(Box::new(expand))); }

fn expand(_: &mut ExtCtxt, _: Span, _: &MetaItem, item: P<Item>) -> P<Item> {
    println!("Hello world!");
    return item; }
```

Based on the comments received, I put the extension as a separate crate, the new app structure is in the screenshot below.

The `Cargo.toml` of `bin` is:

```
[package]
name = "hello_world"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["hasan"]

[dependencies]
extension = { path = "./extension" }
```

The `Cargo.toml` of `lib` is:

```
[package]
name = "extension"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["hasan"]

[dependencies]

[lib]
plugin = true
```

[image]

Comment: Compiler plugins are only available on nightly builds. What compiler version are you using?

Comment: @rodrigo, I've `rustc 1.29.0-nightly (64f7de921 2018-07-12)`

Comment: In the linked post it says that compiler plugins must be in its own `lib` crate, with `plugin = true` in the `Cargo.toml`... Maybe you are writing this code in a `bin` crate?

Comment: @rodrigo I put both files i the `src` folder, both files mean `main.rs` and `lib.rs`

Comment: I think you should create two different crates. One `bin` crate and another `lib` crate. You can create the `lib` crate inside the `bin` directory and in the `Cargo.toml` of the `bin` one you set the `path` of the dependency to point the the `lib` one. And the `Cargo.toml` of the `lib` one can have that `plugin = true`.

Comment: I updated my my question based on your feedback @rodrigo, kindly have a lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what happens when you use unstable features: they change!
The blog post you link is quite old now (2015 maybe?)... Many things will still apply but things are being moved around.

You can find the latest [official documentation here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/plugin.html).

A quick skimming through the docs reveal the first problem is that `rustc::plugin` has been moved to its own crate: `rustc_plugin`. I didn't follow all the documentation but more issues probably follow.